# Unable to disable Domain Partitioning

Tags: trailhead, mydomain, developer-org, enhanced-domains

Recently I have notice that there is no longer an option to disable Partitioned Domains for Trailhead or Developer Orgs. I know this used to be possible as I have some previously created older Trailhead org that have a check box to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_partitioned_domains.htm&type=5), Partitioned Domains are available in Developer Edition orgs, patch orgs, scratch orgs, and Trailhead Playgrounds with enhanced domains and new orgs get partitioned domains by default, and you can’t disable this feature in those orgs.

Comment: Thank you, could you please point me to that doc

Comment: Have already shared doc link above pls review.